# Jenkins pipeline emailext emailextrecipients: Can I also add specific, individual email address?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

In Jenkins pipeline I'm using **email-ext** with `emailextrecipients` as follows:

```
emailext(
    subject: email_subject, 
    mimetype: 'text/html', 
    to: emailextrecipients([[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]), 
    body: email_body
)
```

And I want to add a specific email address, e.g. admin@myshop.com, to the list generated using `emailextrecipients`. I want that addressee (me or a manager or admin) to always get the email, but the addressee might be a culprit or requester and I don't want emailext to send two emails to that addressee.

Is there a way to merge 'admin@myshop.com' with `emailextrecipients`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know how I missed this, but the answer is in the **email-ext** doc. Use the `to:` for the additional email addresses, and use `recipientProviders:` instead of `to: emailextrecipients`:

```
emailext(
    subject: email_subject,
    mimetype: 'text/html',
    to: 'admin@myshop.com',
    recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
    body: email_body
)
```

Comment: Can you please add a link to the email-ext doc with this information

Answer (score 10):

A slight variation to **Generic Ratzlaugh's** answer, in case you need to use conditional logic for email destinations:

```
def recipientProviders = [];
recipientProviders.add([$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider']);
recipientProviders.add([$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']);
recipientProviders.add([$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']);

emailext(
    subject: email_subject,
    mimetype: 'text/html',
    to: 'admin@myshop.com',
    recipientProviders: recipientProviders,
    body: email_body
)
```